# how to execute non sql commands in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

How can execute non sql commands like

```
\connect
\dl
\dt
\du
\d+ table_name
```

...etc

in psycopg2 ??

```
cur.execute("\dl")
```

when  try to do it with cursor , I get error

```
syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \dl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These non-sql commands are specific for the [psql - PostgreSQL interactive terminal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). You cannot execute them with psycopg2, but you can run psql from your app. The below complete example in Python 3.6 uses [subprocess:](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html)

```
import psycopg2
import sys
import subprocess

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', dbname='test', user='postgres')
conn.autocommit = True

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('create table my_table(id int primary key, str text)')

res = subprocess.run('psql -c "\d+ my_table" test postgres', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(res.stdout.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

Output:

```
                                  Table "public.my_table"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 str    | text    |           |          |         | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "my_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Those commands are implemented by the `psql` command-line tool, not by the PostgreSQL server. Some of them (like `\dt`) have SQL equivalents (like `SELECT … FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables` -- [details here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-tables.html)), but others (like `\connect`) do not. If you want to connect to another Postgres server, create a new connection object.